# Using MongoDB with AWS ElasticBean application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an ElasticBean application running (setup with NodeJS) and I wondered what the best way to integrate MongoDB would be. As of now, all I've done is ssh into my eb instance (with the eb cli) and install mongodb. My main worry comes from the fact that the mongo db exists in my instance. As I understand it, that means that my data will most certainly be lost as soon as I terminate my instance. Is that correct? If so the what is the best way to go about hooking en EB app to a MongoDB? Does AWS support that natively without having to go rent a DB on a dedicated server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely do NOT want to install MongoDB on an Elastic Beanstalk instance.

You have a few options for running MongoDB on AWS. You can install it yourself on some EC2 servers (NOT Elastic Beanstalk servers) and handle all the management of that yourself. The other option is to use [mLab](https://mlab.com/) (previously MongoLab) which is a managed MongoDB as a Service provider that works on AWS as well as other cloud services. Using mLab you can easily provision a MongoDB database in the same AWS region as your Elastic Beanstalk servers.

Given the steps involved in setting up a highly-available MongoDB cluster on AWS I generally recommend using mLab instead of trying to handle it yourself. Just know that the free-tier is not very performant and you will want to upgrade to one of the paid plans for your production database.

Answer (score 0):

Been there, done that. As @MarkB suggested it´d be a lot easier to use a SaaS instead.

AWS by itself doesn´t have a native MongoDB support but deppending of your requierements you could find a solution with little or no extra cost (beside EC2 price) on Amazon Marketplace. These images are vendor´s pre-configured production-ready AMIs of popular tools like MongoDB.